# creating a file transfer network using P2P in python

Tags: python-2.7, networking, file-upload, network-programming, p2p

i want to start a big project in networks. i want to do a peer 2 peer network that would able each peer to share files and download them. i thought it could be cool to do it with a Segmented file transfer protocol but that's probably optional. but i have no idea how to start. i found this implementation of a p2p network and i'm currently learning every command in there and how it works. how should i continue? (i want to do this in python) : https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2010-October/079516.html

Answer (score 0):

I think someone beat you to it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent

Comment: yes but the implementation is what i'm looking for.

Comment: A good starting point i found was http://cs.berry.edu/~nhamid/p2p/framework-python.html

Comment: thanks! but that's exactly what i put up there. they say it doesn't work + im not that familiar with the socket.makefile function. how does it work?